# Pivot Table within SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have an SQL query here, which works perfectly fine:

```
select
R.[Source_Loaction] as VendorID
,R.[Article_Nbr]
,A.[Article_Desc]
,S.[Destination_Location] as Site
,AH.[External_Product_SType_Arth_Desc] as Product_Subtype
,datepart (week, R.[Scheduled_Ship_dae]) as WK
,SUM(S.[Major_Ship_Qty]) as UoM
,SUM(R.[Shipment_Qty]) as Qty

from [dbo].[FnR_RECEIVED_SHIPMENT_V] as R

INNER JOIN [dbo].[FnR_SOURCING_V] as S
ON (R.[Article_Nbr]=S.[Article_Nbr] AND R.[Destination_Location]=S.[Destination_Location])
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FnR_EXTERNAL_ARTICLE_V] as AH
ON R.[Article_Nbr]=AH.[Article_Nbr]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FnR_ARTICLE_V] as A
ON R.[Article_Nbr]=A.[Article_Nbr]

Group by 
R.[Source_Loaction]
,R.[Article_Nbr]
,A.[Article_Desc]
,S.[Destination_Location]
,AH.[External_Product_SType_Arth_Desc]
,datepart (week, R.[Scheduled_Ship_dae])
```

I wish to place a PIVOT table as structured HERE:

PIVOT(sum(Qty) for [WK] in ([25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36])) as pivot

These two SQL functions are not working together and I am unsure where to place the pivot.  Could someone assist as to where I have gone wrong on this one?  The items 25 through 36 in the pivot tables are week start dates and this is what I wish to pivot on.

I appreciate any incite.

I am creating a pivot table on qty's based on week function.  Once I can do this, I have my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from 
(
     -- your first query here
) src
PIVOT(sum(Qty) for [WK] in ([25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36])) as pivot
```

as per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: When I attempt this, I receive the following error message:

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.